# possible to use for_each along with count to enable/disable a resource?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create reusable infrastructure  to enable/disable a resource by conditionally setting the count.  The problem is "for_each" & "count" does not work together . Any other way to accomplish this ?

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "network-ip-ranges" {
  count = var.vpc_network_firewall ? 1 : 0
  for_each      = var.subnets
  name          = each.key
  ip_cidr_range = each.value.cidr_block
  region        = each.value.region
  project       = google_project.sharedprojects["Shared-Dev-VPC"].number
  network       = google_compute_network.sc_vpc_network.id
```

Comment: You need to provide values of all your variables, and any errors that you get.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of `for_each` is that you wish to declare one instance of a resource for every element of a given map or set, and so I would suggest reframing your problem statement in this way, disregarding for the moment the specific idea of using `count`:

- If `var.vpc_network_firewall` is true, create one instance for each element of `var.subnets`.
- If `var.vpc_network_firewall` is false, create no instances.

This framing of the problem makes room for a different answer: conditionally choosing between `var.subnets` or an empty map or set.

The details of how to achieve that differ a little depending on whether `var.subnets` is a `set(string)` or a map value, so I'll show both.

If `var.subnets` is a map (which does seem to be the case for you, based on how you are using `each.value` as an object inline):

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "network-ip-ranges" {
  for_each = {
    for k, v in var.subnets : k => v
    if var.vpc_network_firewall
  }
  # ...
}
```

If `var.subnets` is a set of strings:

```
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "network-ip-ranges" {
  for_each = toset([
    for v in var.subnets : v
    if var.vpc_network_firewall
  ])
  # ...
}
```

Both of these are using a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for) with an [`if` clause](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for#filtering-elements) to filter elements.

Because the `if` expression in these examples doesn't include any references to `k` or `v`, this particular `for` expression can either produce one result element for each input element *or* produce no elements at all, which matches my reframing of your problem statement from above, and should achieve the result you want.